# Confirmação antes de excluir registro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um link que ao clicar abre um modal perguntando se o usuário deseja excluir o registro. No link tenho um href que chama uma rota para fazer a exclusão. Como poderia fazer para chamar essa rota somente se clicar no botão de excluir?

Link:

```
<a id="danger-alert" href="{{ route('admin.categories.destroy', $category) }}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete zmdi-hc-lg"></i></a>
```

Função:

```
$('#danger-alert').click(function () {
    swal({
        title: "Deseja excluir o registro?",
        //text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "error",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger waves-effect waves-light',
        confirmButtonText: 'Excluir'
    });
});
```

Comment: Tu diz bloquear o acesso à URL caso o usuário tente acessá-la de outra maneira?

Comment: Eu preciso incluir um botão que o usuario confirme se tem certeza que deseja excluir. Estou usando uma dashboard que tem essa função pronta. Ao clicar no link ele chama a função através do ID que exibe um modal com o botão de cancelar ou excluir. Se ele clicar em excluir continua a execução chamando o a rota que está no href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui encontrar a solução. No caso a lib é a SweetAlert for Bootstrap

```
<a id="danger-alert" data-link="{{ route('admin.categories.destroy', $category) }}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete zmdi-hc-lg"></i></a>

$('#danger-alert').click(function () {
    swal({
          title: "Tem certeza?",
          type: "error",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
          confirmButtonText: "Excluir",
          closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function(){
       window.location.href = $('#danger-alert').attr("data-link");
    });
});
```